# Angular Directive would not update ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I can't seem to find a way to update my ng-model in my directive

My directive looks like this

```
app.directive('DatepickerChanger', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            Model: '=',
            startDate: '=',
            endDate: '=',
        },
        templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
            return '/AngularJS/Directives/msDatepickerTpl.html'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {  
               ngModel = new Date();
        }

    }
});
```

And i use it like this

```
 <DatepickerChanger ng-model="date" required></DatepickerChanger>
```

Where date is a other date object

If i console.log the ng-model, i can see that it's change it's value, but can't see it from the place where i call the directive. anyone got a clue to what im doing worng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it wrong. This ngModel is a [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). Your code should look like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {  
    ngModel.$setViewValue(new Date());
}
```

Also, the directive should be called `datepickerChanger` and referenced in html as `datepicker-changer`

**EDIT**:

You want to update the ngModel after changing the input, for example. One way to do that is use the `bind` function to capture the events of the input field (I cant see your template, but I imagine that will have one input):

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {  
    element.find('input').bind('change', function() {
       // Do something with this.value 
       ngModel.$setViewValue(newDate);
    });
}
```

Comment: i see. i'm Wondering. link's function is run when the directive is init, if i'm not wrong. But isn't there something like a controller that can keep running after the link have been firing?

Comment: You can declare a controller for your directive. But you want update the ngModel after changes in your input thats not the way. I updated my answer.

Comment: So i need to use elemet.find to find the input so i can attach a event handler?

Comment: Its an option. Show me your template so I can give you a real answer.

Comment: Rafael P. Miranda. i tried playing with it a bit and i got it working thanks to you. So thanks.